# How to make QListWidget auto-format the Item's text

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qlistwidget, qtextbrowser

The code below creates a `QTextBrowser` populated with 5 lines. Each line is 100+
characters long. To make all the characters (the letters) visible the `QTextBrowser` reformats the text as soon as the size of the widget is changed.
Try to drag the right-bottom corner of the widget to see how `QTextBrowser` constantly updates the text to keep it in a view.

## QTextBrowser:

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app=QtGui.QApplication([])

textBrowser = QtGui.QTextBrowser()
for i in range(5):
    textBrowser.insertPlainText('MESSAGE-%04d'%i +'-'*100 + '\n')

textBrowser.show()
app.exec_()
```

I wonder if `QListWidget` could be configured to support a "text auto-formating" functionality as well. The code below is exact copy of the one posted above except the `QListWidget` is now used in place of `QTextBrowser`. The `QListWidget` clips the extra characters from view and does nothing in an attempt to reformat the text to make it visible to the user. Is there a way to change this behavior?

## QListWidget:

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app=QtGui.QApplication([])

listWidget = QtGui.QListWidget()
for i in range(5):
    QtGui.QListWidgetItem('ITEM-%04d '%i+'-'*100, listWidget)

listWidget.show()
app.exec_()
```

## EDITED LATER:

Below is the attempt to use `setItemWidget` to substitute `QListWidgetItem` with `QTextBrowser`. But unfortunately the size of the resulted `QTextBrowser` is way too large. If there could be a way to fine tune its size it could be a solution:

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app=QtGui.QApplication([])

class TextBrowser(QtGui.QTextBrowser):
    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        super(TextBrowser, self).__init__(parent)

listWidget = QtGui.QListWidget()
for i in range(5):
    item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem('ITEM-%04d '%i+'-'*100, listWidget)
    itemWidget = TextBrowser()
    itemWidget.setText('ITEM-%04d '%i+'-'*100)
    item.setSizeHint(itemWidget.sizeHint())
    listWidget.setItemWidget(item, itemWidget)

listWidget.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: You mean you want the list item text to wrap, instead of having a scroll bar?

Comment: Correct, I would like `QListWidget` to text wrap the items text every time it is resized. So the entire text is always visible and readable (functionality we see in QTextBrowser).